# TSQL - How to avoid UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, sql-server-2016

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE
    (
        [Id] INT
      , [Misc_Val] VARCHAR(5)
    ) ;

DECLARE @Children TABLE
    (
        [Id]   INT
      , [P_ID] INT
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Parent
VALUES
    ( 1, 'One' )
  , ( 2, 'Two' )
  , ( 3, 'Three' )
  , ( 5, 'Four' ) ;

INSERT INTO @Children
VALUES
    ( 10, 1 )
  , ( 11, 1 )
  , ( 21, 2 )
  , ( 23, 2 )
  , ( 30, 3 )
  , ( 40, 4 ) ;
```

Goal:
To ***efficiently*** output three fields ( [Id] and [IsChild], [Misc_Val] ). Output all records from @Parent table with [IsChild] = 0 and output all MATCHING records from @Child table (@Parent.Id = @Children.P_Id) with [IsChild] = 1.

Expected Output

```
Id  IsChild Misc_Val
1   0       One
2   0       Two
3   0       Three
5   0       Four
10  1       One
11  1       One
21  1       Two
23  1       Two
30  1       Three
```

My try:

```
SELECT  [P].[Id]
      , 0 AS [IsChild]
      , [P].[Misc_Val]
FROM    @Parent AS [P]
UNION ALL
SELECT  [C].[Id]
      , 1
      , [P].[Misc_Val]
FROM    @Parent AS [P]
JOIN    @Children AS [C]
ON      [C].[P_ID] = [P].[Id] ;
```

Is there a better way to do this than using UNION ALL? @Parent and @Children tables are quite big and so am trying to avoid querying the @Parent table twice.

UPDATE: The below answer made me realized something I missed out when creating the post with mocked data. We do need some additional data from @Parent table regardless in the final output.

Comment: Do you have a performance issue? Because if not... don't try and pre-optimise it. A `UNION ALL` is the correct way to solve this problem given you store your data in 2 tables (normally you would use the same table, referencing itself).

Comment: Unfortunately yes, due to the sheer number of rows in both tables, querying @Parent table again is a big hit on the system.

Comment: This is a well written question, however for performance questions you should always post the execution plan of the actual query (not your mocked up query) using [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). You also shouldn't assume you know the best way to improve the performance (remove the `union all` in this case) because that might not be the solution. Your question should be, how can I improve the performance of this query.

Comment: Kind of feels like a LEFT OUTER JOIN here to me.  UNION eliminates duplicates and UNION ALL does not if that helps

Comment: @DaleK, will keep this in mine for future. Thanks.
MarkSchultheiss, yea. I was thinking about left join with derived table and conditional where but can't get my head around that concept. Going to continue tinkering on my local. Thanks

Comment: @DaleK I've had this exact scenario multiple times, and it annoys me that there is no easy way in SQL to express it. `CROSS APPLY` in my answer is not always efficient, especially if the child table is not well indexed. I wish there was a `OUTER WITH INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use `CROSS APPLY` to add the child table to the parent table.**

This may or may not be faster, it can depend on indexing and so forth. You need to check the query plan.

```sql
SELECT  v.Id
      , v.IsChild
      , P.Misc_Val
FROM    @Parent AS P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        P.Id,
        0 AS IsChild
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.Id,
        1
      FROM @Children AS C
      WHERE C.P_ID = P.Id
) v;
```

Note that the first `SELECT` in the apply has no `FROM` and therefore does not do any table access.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Charlieface. I tested this approach (quite interesting btw). The scans and logical reads cut down by half for the @parent table, however, scans, logical reads, and physical reads jumped A LOT. It does index seek on PK where seek predicate = 1st field in the PK (has two fields, returning the 2nd in select).

Comment: Yes it can do that, it often forces a nested loops, which is only good if the child table has good indexing

Comment: Gotcha. It's seeking on PK, where seek predicate is the first key and SELECT is returning the 2nd key from that PK. Do you recommend any indexing improvements I can do to get better query exec plan?

btw, "... scans, logical reads, and physical reads jumped A LOT ..." was meant for the @child table (couldn't edit my original comment).

Comment: You'll have to share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Ok, will have to check with people above my pay-grade if I can do that. Will post if allowed. Thank you